# Difficulty in finding marginal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, variance

Let $X=(X_{1},X_{2})$ have joint pdf.$$f(x_{1},x_{2})=\begin{cases}\frac{e^{-\frac{x_{2}^2}{2}}}{x_{2}\sqrt{2\pi}},\ &\text{if}\ 0<|x_{1}|\le x_{2}<\infty.\\0,\  &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ Then the variance of $X_1$, is for finding out the variance I must need *marginal dist. of $X_1$* $f(x_{1})$? but I am stuck in finding this integral $$\int_{x_{1}}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{x_{2}^2}{2}}}{x_{2}\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ even if need to use total variance formula I need $f_{x_{1}}$ but  I think that will be much more clumsy rather than finding variance by moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to know the marginal distribution of $X_1$ to compute the variance of $X_1$. That is a good thing, since the required integral cannot be evaluated using elementary functions.

By symmetry the mean of $X_1$ is $0$. So the variance is $E(X_1^2)$, which is
$$\int_{x_2=0}^\infty \left(\int_{x_1=-x_2}^{x_2} x_1^2\frac{e^{-x_2^2/2}}{x_2\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dx_1\right) \,dx_2.$$
The inner integral is, after some cancellation,
$$\frac{2}{3\sqrt{2\pi}}x_2^2 e^{-x_2^2/2}.$$ We need to integrate this from $0$ to $\infty$. The integral can be found using the fact that the standard normal has variance $1$.

Comment: thanks@André Nicolas you made it I was not able to see the symmetry first .

Comment: I was meant to say you made it easy.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it is clear now. The joint density lives in the part of the plane above the curve $x_2=-x_1$ (more familiar as $y=|x|$). The density at any height is constant, so there is symmetry about the $x_2$-axis.

Comment: Thank you so much to help me visualize it at first I only understood it mathematically.  The density at any height is constant because pdf do not include $x_1$?

Comment: You are right, that is why. About visualization, without a sketch I would usually not know the appropriate integration bounds, or at least would not be certain.

Comment: what about the conditional expectation of$ X_1$given$X_{2},E(X_{1}|X_{2})$. how  can we calculate it without finding it's pdf. any suggestions @Andre Nicolas. In my point of view no we can not find it out even if we know the two are independent as we still need to find the distribution of one. Also in above problem, do the two r.v. are independent? as the pdf is independent of $x_{1}$ and can we take $1$ as pdf of $x_{1}$??

Comment: By symmetry the conditional expectation of $X_1$ given $X_2$ is $0$. The random variables are not independent. The joint density, when you take account of the part where it is $0$, is not a product. Joint density a product only works when the region is a rectangle (possibly infinite) with sides parallel to the axes. Much more informally, if you know that $X_2$ is "small" then you know that $|X_1$ cannot be large, so information about $X_2$ gives you some information about $X_1$.